# How do I turn a repeated list element with delimiters into a list?

Tags: python, list, csv

I imported a CSV file that's basically a table with 5 headers and data sets with 5 elements.

With this code I turned that data into a list of individuals with 5 bits of information (list within a list):

```
import csv
readFile = open('Category.csv','r')
categoryList = []
for row in csv.reader(readFile):
    categoryList.append(row)
readFile.close()
```

Now I have a list of lists `[[a,b,c,d,e],[a,b,c,d,e],[a,b,c,d,e]...]`

However element 2 (`categoryList[i][2]`) or '`c`' in each list within the overall list is a string separated by a delimiter ('`:`') of variable length. How do I turn element 2 into a list itself? Basically making it look like this:

```
[[a,b,[1,2,3...],d,e][a,b,[1,2,3...],d,e][a,b,[1,2,3...],d,e]...]
```

I thought about looping through each list element and finding element 2, then use the `.split(':')` command to separate those values out.

Answer (score 1):

The solution you suggested is feasible. You just don't need to do it after you read the file. You can do it while taking it as a input in the first place.

```
for row in csv.reader(readFile):
    row[2] = row[2].split(":") # Split element 2 of each row before appending
    categoryList.append(row)
```

**Edit:** I guess you know the purpose of split function. So I will explain `row[2]`.

You have a data such as `[[a,b,c,d,e],[a,b,c,d,e],[a,b,c,d,e]...]` which means each `row` goes like `[a,b,c,d,e]`, `[a,b,c,d,e]`, `[a,b,c,d,e]`, So every row[2] corresponds to `c`. Using this way, you get to alter all `c`'s before you append and turn them in to `[[a,b,c,d,e],[a,b,c,d,e],[a,b,c,d,e]...]`.

Comment: It worked, thank you! Can you explain line 3 of your code and how it's running in the loop itself to turn element 2 into an array? My logic is still weak.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a *list comprehension* on each row and split items containing `':'` into a new *sublist*:

```
for row in csv.reader(readFile):
    new_row = [i.split(':') if ':' in i else i for i in row]
    categoryList.append(new_row)
```

This works if you also have other items in the row that you need to split on `':'`.

---

Otherwise, you can directly split on the index if you only have one item containing `':'`:

```
for row in csv.reader(readFile):
    row[2] = row[2].split(':')
    categoryList.append(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really clear about your structure but if c is a string seperated by : within then try

> list(c.split(':'))

Let me know if it solved your problem

Answer (score 0):

Assume that you have a row like this:

```
row = ["foo", "bar", "1:2:3:4:5", "baz"]
```

To convert item `[2]` into a sublist, you can use

```
row[2] = row[2].split(":")  # elements can be assigned to, yawn.
```

Now the row is `['foo', 'bar', ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'], 'baz']`

To *graft* the split items to the "top level" of the row, you can use

```
row[2:3] = row[2].split(":")  # slices can be assigned to, too, yay!
```

Now the row is `['foo', 'bar', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', 'baz']`

This of course skips any defensive checks of the row data (can it at all be split?) that a real robust application should have.